# http request keep failing in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, xmlhttprequest

I have been trying to find a way that how to get an items from some server by using http request in Flutter.

So I added and edited some of codes that i found but i keep failing to use this.

Here is the code below.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Post> fetchPost() async {
  var params = {                              
    "citycode": Uri.encodeFull("25"),
    "nodeId": Uri.encodeFull("DJB8001793ND"),
  };

  Uri uri = Uri.parse('http://openapi.tago.go.kr/openapi/service/ArvlInfoInqireService/getSttnAcctoArvlPrearngeInfoList'); 
  final newURI = uri.replace(queryParameters: params); 

  final response = await http.get(
    newURI,
    headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "t8iGBTBFQc5nMq9ytuMZQ7jxR8ZMzohG%2F5o0i80f%2BehjFhMpkADfArAvFk%2BjHsPMFFEThQgejzujdpfou%2FDWng%3D%3D"},
  );

  /*
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  print('$responseJson');
  return Post.fromJson(responseJson);
  */
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON.
    return Post.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If that response was not OK, throw an error.
    throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
}

class Post { 
  final String nodeid;
  final String nodenm;
  final int arrtime;
  final int routeno;

  Post({this.nodeid, this.nodenm, this.arrtime, this.routeno});

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      nodeid: json['nodeid'],
      nodenm: json['nodenm'],
      arrtime: json['arrtime'],
      routeno: json['routeno'],
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp(post: fetchPost()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<Post> post; 

  MyApp({Key key, this.post}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Post>(
            future: post,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) { 
                return Text(snapshot.data.nodenm); 
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {          
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I got this error and it is caused by this code below.
and i think the reason is i failed to get a data..but i don't know why.
[image]

```dart
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) { 
                return Text(snapshot.data.nodenm); 
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {          
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }
```

I would like to get an items like
 nodeid
 nodenm
 arrtime
 routeno
in the server below. what should i fix it?
[image]

Comment: you should use `jsonDecode` function to parse the data in json format and use `import 'dart:convert';` to import jsonDecode  library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server is returning you XML, but you are trying to parse that as if it is JSON.

You should try adding an `Accept` header to your request and get the server to return you JSON data, instead of XML:

```dart
headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "...", "Accept": "application/json"},
```